# microsoft access query speed

Tags: performance, ms-access

I am now writing a report about MS Access and I can't find any information about its performance speed in comparison to other alternatives such as Micorsoft SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc... It's obvious that MS Access is going to be the slowest among the rest, but there is no solid documents confirming this other than forums threads, and I don't have the time and resources to do the research myself.

Comment: It may be worth while posting in a pro-Access forum such as http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?app=portal and drawing a line somewhere along the scale.

Comment: The question is absolutely IDIOTIC. You can't compare database engines except for a SPECIFIC TASK. Define the task, and then you can benchmark it.

Comment: yes, you can compare database engines. SQL Server is STABLE, FAST, and EASY TO DEVELOP.  Jet is not stable, it is not dependable, and it is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Access isnt always the slowest.  For fairly simple queries with one user, it is actually quite fast.

but throw a few extra users in there, or use complex joins and it will fall apart on you.

Here is what I could find quickly:

http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/access-vs-sql-server-some-stats-part-1/
http://www.linuxtoday.com/news_story.php3?ltsn=2001-07-27-006-20-RV-SW
http://swik.net/MySQL/MySQL+vs+MS+SQL+Server

Oddly enough, few people compare access to the "real" databases since the user limit is such a limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Microsoft's reasons to upgrade to SQL Server from Access:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/move-access-data-to-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-upsizing-wizard-HA010275537.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've actually seen an Access address book of over 3 million records performing very very fast while being used by hundreds of users. This is however an exception. Access databases decrease in performance and stability as soon as the database is modified while in use and especially if it is modified by more than a couple of users.

Answer (score -2):

yes, Access (Jet) is slow. It's best to move to Access Data Projects- this allows you to use Access forms and reports with SQL Server, a REAL database.

SQL Server is the most popular database anywhere.. has been installed more often than any other database, period.

Comment: Here is some information that confirms my assertion- that SQL Server is more popular then Access.

Embarcadero Technologies recently released the results of a survey to identify the most popular servers in use as on-premise database platforms. The study found Microsoft's SQL Server is the most popular device on the market, as 83 percent of respondents said they use it in their database environments.